# SPI Flash memory programming with small buffer(uC memory)

Tags: microcontroller, spi, uart, memory, flash

I have AVR(or any, doesn't matter) microcontroller and 1 Megabyte SPI flash IC that I want to write to, I can do it already, have no problems with communication between these two.
But so far I write to chip directly from microcontroller, basically I write data to the uC and then I write it to the flash with uC. Microcontrollers do not have big memory inside them, so this method is only good for very small data.
What should I do if I want for example write 1 Mb of data(from PC)?
I mean I have ideas how to do it with some kind of USART or with FTDI chip, but I wonder what is the right/efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Have you tried using a ring buffer yet?

Comment: You mean ring buffer with UART? I was thinking about it, but I wonder if that's the right way. Probably that's the easiest way, yes, but seems too easy. And I guess it will take a lot of time for big chunks of data.

Answer (score 1):

Use FTDI chips to communicate with PC. Its a easiest way to communicate with PC. since, its drivers are readily available on internet. Just design a circuit of FTDI or buy from the market and install drivers. Actually FTDI chips converts USB to TTL serial.
Start UART and SPI interrupts. Whenever you receive data from PC just forward it through SPI. According to me, this will be fast and efficient way.

pankaj